How to check if a cell contains an integer value in onlyoffice macros?
I'm trying to check if a cell in an only office spread sheet contains an integer in an only office macro.
I already checked the API-Documentation but couldn't find anything. However since I keep finding seemingly undocumented functions in blog posts (and similar), I hope that someone knows the answer. Perhaps I'm also missing something basic regarding calculation functions in oo-macros. (I'm relatively new to js)
Alternatively I could implement this as a custom function, however I would find it strange, that I'd have to resort to this for a seemingly easy task. If this is required, how would I go about that?
(function()
{   
    var sheet = Api.GetActiveSheet();  // Get the active sheet
    var cellValue = sheet.GetRangeByNumber(row, 6).GetValue(); // get the value 
      
     if (MOD(cellValue) === 0) { //<-- WHAT needs to go here?
          alert("value is integer");
         }  
})();

